# Websphere .war doesn't update UI files after hot deployment

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, websphere

I'm working with IntelliJ in a JavaEE (JSP/JSF) project, and with Websphere Application Server 8. When I do an 'update classes and resources' in IntelliJ after doing some change in CSS or in a facelet, the war inside the following path is not being updated:

```
IBM\WebSphere\Profiles\myproject\installedApps\iap\myproject_exploded.ear\myProjectWeb.war
```

However, the artifact on my workspace folder is being updated without any issue.

To get the changes in my server I have to restart the server.

I really appreciate any help that you can provide.